# Combining data elements in a Matlab binary vector

Tags: matlab, binary

I want to know whether there is a matlab function to combine data in an matlab binary data array according to another separate integer array. Please see below example.

```
d = [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0]
c = [2 2 3 2 4]
```

I want to add the elements of **d** array according to the **c** array, Thet means,
perform modulo-2 addition of add the first 2 elements `d(1)+d(2)` 
,then mod-2 of `d(3)+d(4)`
,then mod-2 of `d(5)+d(6)+d(7)`
etc...

Really appreciate if someone can let me know a matlab function to perform this with out using too many for loops.

Thanks.

Comment: Your example isn't very clear, can you make your text match your `d` and `c` a little better?

Comment: I am aso confused by what operation the c array signifies. Please clarify.

Comment: Please see above, I have made some changes...hope it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

One way is to first create an array that has 2x1, 2x2, 3x3, 2x4 etc., and then use `accumarray` to sum up the elements in `d`

```
idxVector = zeros(size(d));
idxVector(cumsum(c(1:end-1))+1) = 1;
idxVector = cumsum(idxVector) + 1;
out = accumarray(idxVector(:),d(:))

out =

     1
     1
     2
     1
     2
```

Comment: The problem here is that I want to perform modulo 2 addition with the binary data.

Comment: @anne: can you please write out the result of the addition?

Answer (score 0):

```
mod(diff([0 arrayfun(@(n) sum(d(1:n)), cumsum(c))]),2)
```